# How to use a literal curly brace "{" in XAML?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, escaping

I need put in } and { in a XAML ConvertParameter without it being interpreted:

```
ConverterParameter = "{0}/{1}"
```

...which does not work. How to do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use:

```
ConverterParameter = "{}{0}/{1}"
```

More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/escape-sequence-markup-extension).

Answer (score 20):

Use [{} as the escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/escape-sequence-markup-extension).

```
ConverterParameter = "{}{0}/{1}"
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who got here looking for the answer for WinRT-XAML. The escape sequence is `\` sign. Although [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758283.aspx) states `'` should work but on the other hand [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) example uses `\` (which actually worked for me).

Comment: I don't know if something has changed, but in UWP it is also {} and not \ and also not '