# d:DesignInstance freezes up my designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I've got the following `CollectionViewSource`:

```
<CollectionViewSource 
    x:Key="csvDataItemsGrouped" 
    IsSourceGrouped="True" 
    Source="{Binding DayItems, Mode=OneWay}" 
    ItemsPath="CalendarItems"
    d:Source="{Binding Groups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=sData:SampleWeekDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True} }">
</CollectionViewSource>
```

My `SampleWeekDataSource` looks like this:

```
public sealed class SampleWeekDataSource {        

    public SampleWeekDataSource() {
        _groups = new ObservableCollection<DayItem> {
            new DayItem(DateTime.Now) {
                CalendarItems = new ObservableCollection<CalendarItem> {
                    new CalendarItem(1, "test 1", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, "tralala")
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DayItem> _groups = new ObservableCollection<DayItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<DayItem> Groups {
        get { return this._groups; }
    }
```

When I try to rebuild the project, The designer shows the item briefly (but not the header item) and the designer just hangs, with the process eating up a whole core.

Am I doing something wrong with test data? Thanks!

**Edit:**

So I disabled my `GroupStyle` and now the designer doesn't freeze anymore. Could it be that my `GroupStyle` code isn't correct? It's this:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
                                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0, 0, 12, 10" />
                                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="10" />
                                    </Style>
                                </GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >

                                        <TextBlock 
                                           Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                           Text="{Binding DayDate, Converter={StaticResource cvtStringFormat}, ConverterParameter=\{0:ddd d\}}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

                            </GroupStyle>

                        </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

**Edit 2:**
When I follow up on the visual studio examples it still is going to freeze.

Comment: Does anything interesting happen inside the cvtStringFormat Converter?

Comment: I'm also seeing a couple of options for passing that kind of ConverterParameter here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312371/how-use-curly-brace-in-xaml . Is it possible that your escape sequence isn't right?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Goobering! Nothing fancy happens in the converter but a .ToString("d") on a date. As for your curly braces, the msdn article here also shows using \ as escape character works. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

So I've did some digging and I think I found the problem. I've been programming with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 and the new Universal App project.

I've stripped my whole application and created a very simple grouped observable collection with two strings. The same happened with the designer. Items were shown in the designer. However, group template still wasn't shown. And yes, after a few seconds, the whole designer process hung and I had to restart the designer.

Now as final attempt, I tried to recreate the exact same issue on Visual Studio 2013 and the 'old' universal template. Guess what, everything works perfectly! So there's still something fishy going on in Visual Studio 2015 or Windows 10.